# Upgrade Opendj from 2.6.4 to 3.5.3 for replication server

Tags: ldap, openam, opendj, forgerock

I'm trying to perform an upgrade on an environments 2 OpenDJ directory servers with 1 standalone replication server between them referring to the [3.5 Upgrade doc](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3.5/install-guide/index.html#upgrade-repl). However, I could not find information on the order of upgrade for replication topology with standalone replication server. Should we go with upgrade of Directory servers first followed by replication, or vice versa. Can upgrade script identify between replication and directory servers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, replication is compatible between versions.

Comment: Thanks @Ludovic Poitou, what would be the order of upgrade that needs to be followed, standalone replication server or directory servers.

Comment: I could not find steps to follow for upgrade on standalone replication server in 3.5 Opendj Upgrade doc. Could you probably suggest on where i can get that information. The interactive upgrade asks about recalculating index, which i think is not needed on a replication server?

Comment: A standalone RS is no different from a replicated DS with no database backend. If there is no backend, recalculating indexes will be fast as there should be nothing to do. There is no order required nor recommended.